# jQuery Mobile pop up notification on form submit

Tags: php, forms, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery review page that I am submitting data to a submit.php page to email the data. As of now on success I have it going to a "success" page but I would rather (if possible) when you submit on the review.php it a pop notification lets you know if it mailed or echos an error. Any help would be great.

Review.php

```
    <script>
        function onSuccess(data, status)
        {
            data = $.trim(data);
            $("#notification").text(data);
        }

        function onError(data, status)
        {
            // handle an error
        }        

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function(){

                var formData = $("#callAjaxForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "order.php",
                    cache: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: onSuccess,
                    error: onError
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

<form id="callAjaxForm">
                <ul>
                <?php


                    if (is_array($_REQUEST)) {
                        foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $val) {

                            // This code should support the checkboxes and multiple selects
                            if (is_array($val)) {
                                foreach ($val as $val2) {
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='" . $key . "[]' value='" . $val2 . "' />";
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "<input type='hidden' name='" . $key . "' value='" . $val . "' />";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </ul>
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Submit.php

```
 if($from == '') {print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($name == '') {print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
 $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $body, $additional_headers); 
 $send3 = mail($name2, $subject2, $autoreply2, $additional_headers); 
 $result = 'success';

 if($send) 
 {echo json_encode($result);} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please review your information"; } 
 }
}
```

Comment: use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (or the shorthand method [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) ) to submit the form, and on success/failure you can do a pop-up.

Comment: @Sean I added a script to the code above. Is that something on the lines you were talking about?

Comment: Yes, that looks good. You will also need to add `id="submit"` to your submit button since you binding the click - `$("#submit").click(function(){...});`

Comment: Also, since you are using jquery mobile, you could use a dialog widget - http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/ instead of just echoing the text -`$("#notification").text(data);`

Comment: @Sean this seems like it should work but on submit it doesnt post to the order.php, instead in the address bar it looks like it adds the array of data that should be submitting.

Comment: try moving your `return false;` to the begining of your ajax, as it might be submitting your form faster than your ajax call can run - `$("#submit").click(function(){ return false; ...`. By seeing `order.php?...` in your address  bar, it means your form submitted normally. You could also use [`event.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) - `$("#submit").click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: @Sean changing the `return false` didnt work. I noticed with the original code I got it to work but I have to submit the form twice